# File Attributes doesn't work

Tags: perl

i am trying to create a file that is read only and then check if it's readable and writable using File Attributes, but it returnes always that it is readable and writable.

what am i doing wrong?

```
  use strict;
  use Fcntl;
  sysopen(DATA, "file.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDONLY );
  print DATA "Bob\n";
  close (DATA); 

  my $file='file.txt';
  my (@description,$size);
  if (-e $file)
   {
    push @description, 'readable' if (-r _);
    push @description, 'writable' if (-w _);
    push @description, (($size = -s _)) ? "$size bytes" : 'empty';
    print "$file is ", join(', ',@description),"\n";
    }
```

here what is printted:
[image]

can someone help me please?

Comment: The Mode (`O_CREAT | O_RDONLY`) simply declares what you intend to do with the file handle while you've got it open.  If you want to set permissions in the file system, that's a whole different parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The [umask](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/umask.html) value of your process, together with the default [PERMS](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen.html) value of 0666 gives you the writable file.  Either change your `umask` or add a PERMS argument to `sysopen`.  For example to get a read-only file, when you default umask is 0022, you could do:

```
sysopen(DATA, "file.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, 0466 );
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the OP's umask — the file created already tests true for writability, after all.  There is something wrong with the flags passed to sysopen, however.  See my answer.

Comment: @pilcrow The OP stated that a read-only file was desired, not one that is both readable and writable.